# Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object on a SharePoint Page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I encountered the following error when I navigate to Home Page, Site Settings Page in my SharePoint site.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
>   +134    Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()
>   +44    Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext
>   serviceContext) +329
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalAvailable()
>   +44    Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.EnsureMySiteUrls()
>   +60    Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalMySiteUrlAvailable()
>   +15    Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>   +91    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2427
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4016;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016

Comment: Did you try to perform an IISReset on the server running the user profile service application and if needed restart this service?

Comment: i tried that. but it's not work.

Comment: I think there is some error on your page. pls open another page

Comment: I have 10 local site's in sharepoint. In all of the sharepoint Site's, when i navigate to Site Actions -> Site Settings-> then click anyone in  
Galleries i got this error..  This error occured in my Central administration site also.

Comment: any recent customizations I would try to roll-back...Including features/css/masterpages

Comment: recently i enabled the "terminal services" in the server. Is this causes the error?

Answer (score 5):

I sloved the issue by:-

1. Stopped the User profile sync service
2. Stopped user profile service application
3. Recycled SecurityTokenServiceAppPool with re-typing credentials
4. Started User Profile service
5. Started Sync service

For more information Please see the below url:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-AU/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/f06b5803-1c71-4203-b46a-1c22ee646b59

Comment: this trick doesnt work to me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the user profile service , that will resolve the issue.. i do not need that service so i did that and it worked for me...